# Clicking a button by class name using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Probably a silly question, but I have spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure this out. I am building a scrapper bot using selenium in python, and I am just trying to click a button on a web page. The web page opens and resizes...

```
def initalize_browser():
driver.get("**website name**")
driver.maximize_window()
```

but I cannot get it to click a specific button. This is the buttons HTML code:

```
<button class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref" onclick="window.location ='/medical'" onkeypress="window.location='/medical'">
                            Medical and Hospital Costs
                        </button>
```

And this is my code:

```
 click_button=driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="mx-auto green-btn btnHref")

 click_button.click()
```

This is the error I get for this code:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mx-auto green-btn btnHref"}`

I have tried out so many variations of this, including:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref"]').click()
```

Where I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'`

I have also checked to see if there are perhaps any other attributes with the same class name, but there is not. Any help would be super appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Any particular error you are getting?

Comment: Finding by class does not work if you pass more than one class like this. You should use xpath or css. What does your `find_element_by_xpath` call return?

Comment: The option with XPATH should work. To answer that, we need to see the error. But it's also possible that there are some iframes on the page. Could you share the page's source code or just check if there is any `<iframe>` tag inside it?

Comment: @theNishant Hello! So I ran print(driver.page_source) and the error I am getting is that "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mx-auto green-btn btnHref"}". Any advice on what I can try?

Comment: @maciek97x Hey! I get this return when I run find_element_by_xpath..."AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'".

Comment: @EugenyOkulik Hello there, yes you are right I should have included the errors, my apologies. My comments above showcase them. The website name is https://www.fairhealthconsumer.org/. If you have some spare time to take a peek at it, I would appreciate it so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `find_element_by_xpath` is deprecated now. Use this line:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref"]').click()
```

instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref"]').click()
```

And be sure you have this in imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

The locator `click_button=driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="mx-auto green-btn btnHref")` doesn't work because `By.CLASS_NAME` needs only one class name to find an element, but you gave it 3 class names. The html attribute `class` consists of a list of elements divided by space. So, in this html code

```html
<button class="mx-auto green-btn btnHref" onclick="window.location ='/medical'" onkeypress="window.location='/medical'">
                            Medical and Hospital Costs
                        </button>
```

the attribute `class` has 3 class names `mx-auto`, `green-btn` and `btnHref`
You can't use all the 3 classes with `By.CLASS_NAME` but you can use all of them using the `By.XPATH`

Comment: You are seriously the best!!! Thank you so much, super useful knowledge. I appreciate it a lot